# build boost with -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0

Tags: c++, gcc, boost

I need to build boost 1.62 on gcc 6.3 with option -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0...

Can I doing this so:

```
./b2 --cxxflags="-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0" --prefix=/usr/local install -j5
```

or boost 1.62 can't be compiled with this options?

Comment: Make it display complete build commands when building and see if `-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0` is in the command lines.

Answer (score 2):

I did next:

```
./b2 define=_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 install -j5
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is the correct way.

See e.g. similar instructions here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/locale/doc/html/status_of_cpp0x_characters_support.html

Comment: i am trying this .. the above gives me permission error so i tried the below cmd. Is this correct ?
./b2 install -j8 variant=release define=_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 stage

Comment: @PrashantNaik `b2 install` probably installs into `/usr` or `/usr/local` by default, so you would need root permissions. That's not related to this question at all.